# NGINX user agent blocking for specific subdirectory

Tags: nginx, webserver

I'm trying to block a certain user agent from accessing a certain subdirectory in NGINX.

I tried doing this:

```
       location ~ /subdir {
       if ( $http_user_agent ~ (BOT)) {
        return 403;
    }
       }
```

This however blocks everyone from accessing said directory, as if the if directive is being completely ignored. I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: The `location ~ /subdir { }` block itself probably breaks your configuration.

Comment: @RichardSmith Are you saying I shouldn't be using the location block for this? What is the correct way to do something like this then?

Comment: To answer your question correctly, it would help to see the entire `server` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith showing the entire server block isn't really feasible (it's auto-generated and really big), i also tried it without using the location block and i get the same behavior (only this time i get a 403 on everything obviously) , is there anything i should look for specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With complex Nginx configurations, adding another [`location` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) is never simple. It may be easier to implement this using [`map` blocks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) instead.

The `map` block must be placed in `http` context, for example, just **above** the start of the `server` block.

```
map $request_uri $target_subdir {
~*^/subdir/   1;
}

map $http_user_agent $access_denied {
~*BOT         $target_subdir;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($access_denied) { return 403; }
    ...
}
```

The `map` blocks are cascaded. If the user agent matches, then the requested URI is evaluated. Only if both return true will the access be denied.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Another thing, how would I go about doing the reverse? I.e. allowing only access only to user agents containing "BOT"? I thought just  modifying ~*BOT into   !~*BOT would work but it doesn't, that is, everyone can connect when I do that.

Comment: Also another thing, nginx uses the default nginx error page when blocking user agents despite there being an error_page directive for custom error pages.

Comment: To reverse the logic, use `map $http_user_agent $access_denied { ~*BOT 0; default $target_subdir; }`

Comment: Yes this works great, thanks again. Do you have any idea why the error_page directive gets ignored though? It otherwise works, that is I get a static custom error page both when I manually trigger an error and when I put a return status code in a  location block,  but when triggering  the user agent block I always get the default nginx error page instead.

Comment: This rule (if triggered) prevents access to your regular website, **including** the error page.

Comment: I see. So it's not possible for the rule to respect the error_page directive and serve the custom error pages I have defined?

Comment: Not without considering the entire server block.